# Хочу использовать один макет Fragment и при клике в NavigationDrawer передавать туда RecylcerView с разным контентом

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview, android-navigation-drawer

Хочу использовать один макет Fragment и при клике в NavigationDrawer передавать туда RecylcerView с разным контентом.Помогите пожалуйста доработать

Вот собственно мой код:
MainActivity

```
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                            switch (drawerItem.getIdentifier()){
                                case 0:
                                    //Insert Arguments
                                    Fish_Plants_Fragment fish_plants_Fragment = new Fish_Plants_Fragment();
                                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                    args.putInt(KEY_FISH, position);
                                    fish_plants_Fragment.setArguments(args);
                                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.rv, fish_plants_Fragment).commit();
                                    break;
```

а вот сам Фрагмент:

```
public class Fish_Plants_Fragment extends Fragment {


private static final String KEY_FISH = "fish";
private static final String KEY_PLANT = "plant";


public static Fish_Plants_Fragment (){
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    Fish_Plants_Fragment fish_plants_Fragment = new Fish_Plants_Fragment();
    fish_plants_Fragment.getArguments().getInt(KEY_FISH, position);

    return fish_plants_Fragment;

}
```

}

Comment: Во фрагменте невозможный код какой-то. Конструкторов во фрагментах быть не должно, они не могут быть статическими и правила именования классов у вас нарушены. Аргументы из `onCreate` метода вытаскивайте

Comment: Cпасибо ) А в Мэин активити все правильно ?

Comment: Смотря что вам нужно - у вас будут для каждго пункта меню новый фрагмент создаваться с разными аргументами

Comment: Мне в принципе так и нужно, извените пожалуйста а у вас нет случайно инфы или кусочка кода из фрагмента как передавать туда аргумент ?

Comment: Аргументы вы уже передали. Петерь просто в `onCreate` фрагмента вытащите их так `int someInt = getArguments().getInt(KEY_FISH, 0);`

Comment: Большое вам спасибо )))

Comment: а в чём состоит вопрос? «помогите доработать» — это не вопрос. (предвосхищая дополнения: «как сделать/что ещё добавить, чтобы заработало?» — это тоже не вопрос с точки зрения базы знаний, которой является этот сайт).

Answer (score 1):

```js
package su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.R;

public class FragmentBag extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bag, container, false);
    }
}
```

```html
package su.mmm.www.bomj;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentBag;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentHome;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentJob;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentMap;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentMarket;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.Fragments.FragmentStatus;
import su.mmm.www.bomj.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);
        }

        setupNavigationDrawerContent(navigationView);

        //First start (Inbox Fragment)
        setFragment(0);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupNavigationDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.bag:
                                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                setFragment(0);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.home:
                                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                setFragment(1);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.job:
                                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                setFragment(2);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.market:
                                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                setFragment(3);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.status:
                                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                setFragment(4);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.map:
                                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                                } else {
                                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                setFragment(5);
                                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                                return true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
}

    public void setFragment(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentBag fragmentBag = new FragmentBag();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentBag);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentHome fragmentHome = new FragmentHome();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentHome);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentJob fragmentJob = new FragmentJob();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentJob);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentMarket fragmentMarket = new FragmentMarket();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMarket);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentStatus fragmentStatus = new FragmentStatus();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentStatus);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentMap fragmentMap = new FragmentMap();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragmentMap);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```